# Count Items in SQL / XML Import via OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

i made an Import from an XML File in SQL Server 2012.
All works, but following Problem:
In the XML File there was two Items(or more, or less), and the posid (posnummer) is set to '1' for the first Item. For the second Item i search for a solution the the PosId is increased for '1' like:
"set @Posnummer = @Posnummer + 1" 
I found not point where i can insert this code.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @bt varchar(30) = 'F';
DECLARE @Posnummer int = 1;
DECLARE @CurrentCustNo varchar(30) = '1006';

  insert into BELEGP(Kennung, Belegtyp, Belegnummer, Posnummer, Postext, Menge,     Eingabemenge, Editmenge, Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Preismenge, Einzelpreis, Gesamtpreis, Netto, Adressnr)

   SELECT  NEWID() as Kennung,
       @bt as Belegtyp,
       Myorder.j.value('OrderNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Belegnummer,
       @Posnummer as  Posnummer,
       @Posnummer as  Postext,
       MyItem.j.value('Quantity[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Menge,
       MyItem.j.value('Quantity[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Eingabemenge,
       MyItem.j.value('Quantity[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Editmenge,
       MyItem.j.value('Id[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Artikelnummer,
       MyItem.j.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Bezeichnung,
       MyItem.j.value('TotalPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Preismenge,
       MyItem.j.value('TotalPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Einzelpreis,
       MyItem.j.value('TotalPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Gesamtpreis,
       MyItem.j.value('UnityPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Netto,
       @CurrentCustNo as Adressnr

 FROM (
 SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
 FROM
 OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\shop\xml\Bestellungen.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS k(x))
 AS k(x)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Orders/Order') AS MYorder(j)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Orders/Order/Addresses/BillingAddress') AS MYAddresses(j)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Orders/Order/LineItems/LineItem') AS MYItem(j)
```

How can i do this Count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@Posnummer as  Posnummer,
@Posnummer as  Postext,
```

with

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Myorder.j.value('OrderNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)')) as  Posnummer,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Myorder.j.value('OrderNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)')) as  Postext,
```

I don't know if `OrderNumber[1]` is unique per record. If not, try to find a unique combination to use in the `ORDER BY` expression.